# Django ModelForm multiple check boxes aren't working

Tags: python, django-forms

I'm working on an application form by using the Django model and  ModelForm class, in the application, it has multiple checkboxes. when I submit the form it is showing the error that the selected choice isn't a valid choice. I used the CheckboxSelectMultiple widget to select checkboxes. If anyone knows plz help me.

```
 Models.py

 from django.db import models
 from django.urls import reverse

class Application(models.Model):


   genres1=(
   ('classical','Classical'),
   ('rock','Rock'),
   ('musical Theater','Musical Theater'),
   ('country','country'),
   ('blues','Blues'),
   ('christian Contemporary','Christian Contemporary'),
   ('gospel','Gospel'),
   ('other','Other'),
   )

   languages1=(
    ('english','English'),
    ('spanish','Spanish'),
    ('german','German'),
    ('chinese','Chinese'),
    ('hindi','Hindi'),
    ('french','French'),
    ('russian','Russian'),
    ('turkish','Turkish'),
    )
   firstname=models.CharField(max_length=50)
   lastname=models.CharField(max_length=50)
   Email=models.EmailField()
   phonenumber=models.CharField(max_length=15)
   genres=models.CharField(max_length=50, choices=genres1)
   languages=models.CharField(max_length=50, choices=languages1)



def __str__(self):
    return self.firstname
```

forms.py

```
from django import forms
from django.forms import ModelForm
from .models import Application

class application(ModelForm):
   genres1=(
   ('classical','Classical'),
   ('rock','Rock'),
   ('musical Theater','Musical Theater'),
   ('country','country'),
   ('blues','Blues'),
   ('christian Contemporary','Christian Contemporary'),
   ('gospel','Gospel'),
   ('other','Other'),
)

languages1=(
    ('english','English'),
    ('spanish','Spanish'),
    ('german','German'),
    ('chinese','Chinese'),
    ('hindi','Hindi'),
    ('french','French'),
    ('russian','Russian'),
    ('turkish','Turkish'),
)
 genres=forms.MultipleChoiceField(required=True,widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple,choices=genres1)
 languages=forms.MultipleChoiceField(required=True,widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple,
 choices=languages1)
 class Meta:
    model=Application
    fields = '__all__'
```

views.py

```
 from django.shortcuts import render,redirect, get_object_or_404
 from onlinetutors.models import Category,tutors
 from .forms import application
 from .models import Application

 def registration(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
    form=application(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        form.save()
        firstname=form.cleaned_data['firstname']
        lastname=form.cleaned_data['lastname']
        Email=form.cleaned_data['Email']
        phonenumber=form.cleaned_data['phonenumber']
        genres=form.cleaned_data['genres']
        languages=form.cleaned_data['languages']
        form=Application(firstname=firstname,lastname=lastname,Email= Email,phonenumber=phonenumber,
        languages=languages,genres=genres)

        form.save()
        return redirect("/thankyou/")
else:
    form=application()
return render(request,"registration.html",{"form":form})
```

Answer (score 0):

i think the problem might be occuring because you repeated generes1 and languages1 choices in the form.py. Try delete that that is genere1 and languages1 choices. The form.py will use the choices from the models.py. Not too sure but try that and see.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, I tried but still, it is not working.

Comment: Issue solved, I installed this library , Django-multiselectfield. It is working fine now.